# Delete records from 2 tables with 1 query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to delete records from 2 different tables that are linked via job#
One table contains dates for completion and I need to delete all records that were completed between 1999 and 2001. In the second table I need to delete all phases of the job where Job number from table 1 match job number in table 2

I've researched a bit and came up with something like this but when running it I receive "Too Many Fields Selected"

DELETE a.*,b.*
FROM PUB_jc_job a
LEFT JOIN PUB_jc_phase b
ON b.jph_job = a.job_num
WHERE PUB_jc_job.job_compdate BETWEEN #3/31/1999#  AND #12/31/2001#

Comment: PROPER QUERY AFTER SETTING RELATIONSHIP TO ENFORCE ON DELETE CASCADE:

 DELETE * 
FROM PUB_jc_job
WHERE PUB_jc_job.job_compdate BETWEEN #3/31/1999#  AND #12/31/2001#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove dot(.) from table alias "a., b." and retry.

Comment: I'm deleting a.*,b.* So I cannot delete the . otherwise I will receive a syntax error

Comment: don't know MS ACCESS but standard is to only mention table alias in delete query. On the other hand check the cascading rule in your database if the tables are in parent/child relationship. Enforce "on delete cascade" and this way,  when you delete from parent table, all rows from child table will be deleted too.

Comment: this worked, I re worked my query after looking into the relationship and checking the "enforce on delete cascade." turned my query into DELETE * from  PUB_jc_job WHERE (dates between) and that also deleted all records from my child table. Thanks(:

Answer (score 0):

DELETE a, b FROM PUB_jc_job a INNER JOIN PUB_jc_phase b ON b.jph_job = a.job_num WHERE PUB_jc_job.job_compdate BETWEEN #3/31/1999# AND #12/31/2001#

Comment: Please, do not just post code as an answer. Rather explain, what the code does and what makes it work.